# Angularjs allowing the user to input only numbers and forward slash(/)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added a directive which will allow the user to input only numbers, But I also want the directive to restrict forward slash also. Below is the logic inside the directive

```
 if (text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                alert(transformedInput);

                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
```

Can any one tell me what is the pattern I should use so that the above directive will allow only numnbers and forward slash(/)

Comment: Try `/[^\d\/]+/g`.

Comment: It should allow numbers also

Comment: The `\d` is short for `[0-9]`. Check out https://regex101.com/ it's really helpful when testing regex.

Comment: @JosephWebber I tried your code. It's allowing everything , I mean numbers,chars and special characters

Comment: Try it without the `+`. I realized too late that it was unnecessary and couldn't edit my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Regex `^[0-9\/]+$`

which will allow only Numbers and Forward Slashes.

Check The [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/x12Pqc/1)